# URL rewrite blog.domain.com to www.domain.com/blog

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I thought this was pretty simple, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.  I put in my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/index.php [L,R=301]
```

I looked at two other questions here, one recommended ProxyPass, which didn't seem to work either.

My other thought was a VirtualHost for blog.domain.com.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my .htaccess I use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    (^|.)blog\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    (^|.)blog\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [L]
```

Note that I use `(^|.)` for people who would write `www.blog.domain.com`!
Dont forget to handle https also.